# Convert object to json using RestSharp only

Tags: c#, post, restsharp

I've created a small class like this one.

```
public class Device
    {
        public Device()
        {
        }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "u_friendly_name")]
        //[SerializeAs(Name = "u_friendly_name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In order to map "Name" to "u_friendly_name" (as it should be in json) I've added a DeserializeAs declaration. My first question here is.. do I need both DeserializeAs and SerializeAs if I want to POST/GET json or would DeserializeAs suffice?

Doing a GET like this works perfectly. It automatically manages to get the json and cast it to a device as required. However, doing a POST wasn't as simple...

```
public Device GetDevice(string guid)
{
    var request = new RestRequest("api/now/table/x_device", Method.GET);
    request.RootElement = "result";

    var devices = client.Execute<List<Device>>(request);
    return devices.Data.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Guid == guid);
}
```

I'm trying to do a POST like this.

```
        public void RegisterDevice()
        {
            Device device = new Device();
            device.Name = Environment.MachineName;

            var request = new RestRequest("api/now/table/x_device", Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody(device); // HERE

            Console.WriteLine(request.Parameters[0]);

            var response = client.Execute(request);
        }
```

The problem is that the object isn't translated into json. Instead of having "u_friendly_name" in the json output I see "Name". I know this can be solved using Json.Net such as:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(device);
```

But that would also require me to add another dependency to my project and add the JsonProperty declaration to my class. I have been able to get POST working with Json.NET, but not GET and vise versa.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction of how to serialize my class using (preferably) only RestSharp?

**Edit:** After reading a lot of posts on stackoverflow, I get the impression that RestSharp just isn't suitable for deserialization. I found the following link that uses a custom json serializer and while POST works great, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with GET: http://bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer/

```
public Device GetDevice(string guid)
{
    var request = new RestRequest("api/now/table/x_device", Method.GET);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.JsonSerializer = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default;
    request.RootElement = "result";

    var devices = client.Execute<List<Device>>(request);
    return devices.Data.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Guid == guid);
}
```

The only thing that works is setting both:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "u_friendly_name")]
[DeserializeAs(Name = "u_friendly_name")]
```

But that shouldn't be necessary I hope?

**Edit2:** I have manged to get POST to work by adding the "AddHandlers" to the RestSharp client as mentioned in the blog post above. I have also changed my class and added a "Devices" definition.

```
public class Devices
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "result")]
    public List<Device> devices { get; set; }
}

public class Device
    {
        public Device()
        {
        }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "u_friendly_name")]
        //[SerializeAs(Name = "u_friendly_name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now my function looks like this and works as intended:

```
public Device GetDevice(string guid)
{
    var request = new RestRequest("api/now/table/x_uia_sdm_device", Method.GET);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.JsonSerializer = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default;

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var deviceList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Devices>(response.Content);
    return deviceList.devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Guid == guid);
}
```

Json:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "u_guid": "12345678",
      "u_friendly_name": "DeviceA",
      "sys_mod_count": "1",
      "sys_updated_on": "2017-03-09 11:58:50",
      "sys_tags": "",
      "u_config_override": "log_level_local = 5",
      "u_running_version": "1.0.0",
      "sys_id": "abcdefg",
      "sys_created_on": "2017-03-07 12:25:06",
      "u_reference_record": "",
      "u_status": "Provisioned",
      "sys_created_by": "foo@bar.no"
    },
    {
      "u_guid": "34567890",
      "u_friendly_name": "DeviceB",
      "sys_mod_count": "0",
      "sys_updated_on": "2017-03-08 13:23:06",
      "sys_tags": "",
      "u_config_override": "",
      "u_running_version": "",
      "sys_id": "abcdefg",
      "u_application": "",
      "u_reference_record": "",
      "u_status": "",
      "sys_created_by": "foo@bar.no"
    }
  ]
}
```

Even though it now works my initial question still stands. If possible I would love to remove Json.Net and only use RestSharp.